# How to read csv file in Python if the file can but does not have to contain headers in first line?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file in Python using `csv.DictReader`. I need to handle both cases:

1. when headers are present in the first line:

```
col1,col2
foo,bar
```

2. when they are omitted:

```
foo,bar
```

I can assume that headers are always `col1,col2` if they are provided.
I tried to use `fieldnames` parameter, but then headers are treated as values when they are present:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=['col1','col2'])
print(list(reader))
```

Output:

```
[{'col1': 'col1', 'col2': 'col2'}, {'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'}]
```

instead of:

```
[{'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'}]
```

Using `csv.DictReader` without `fieldnames` parameter works when headers are present but returns empty list when there are no headers.

Comment: There's no silver bullet here. You'll need to write code wherever you are using this data to check if that first item in the reader is a header row or not, and ignore or remove accordingly. `clean_reader_list = [x for x in list(reader) if x['col1'] != 'col1']` or `clean_reader_list = list(reader)[1:] if list(reader)[0]['col1'] == 'col1' else list(reader)` or what-have-you.

Comment: You could remove the first row, if all keys equal all values (would indicate headers found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at reading the first row and if it is not the same as your expected headers, go back to the start of the file via `seek()`

Given "in1.csv"

```
col1,col2
foo,bar
```

Given "in2.csv"

```
foo,bar
```

Then

```py
import csv

fieldnames=['col1','col2']
for file_name in ["in1.csv", "in2.csv"]:
    with open(file_name, "r") as file_in:
        if file_in.readline().strip() != ",".join(fieldnames):
            file_in.seek(0)
        results = list(csv.DictReader(file_in, fieldnames=fieldnames))
    print(results)
```

Should give you:

```
[{'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'}]
[{'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 'bar'}]
```

Comment: You don’t need to try to manually parse the CSV: just open with the DictReader like normal and if the first row matches `{'col1': 'col1', 'col2': 'col2'}` then discard the row.

Comment: @ZachYoung  How is there a practical difference between "see if you need to rewind" vs "see if you need to delete the first row"?

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful question :) For the specific problem, "how do I deal with a CSV that may or not have a header?", and for the general problem, "how do I deal with a CSV...?", I want to encourage anyone asking to learn how to use the csv module to solve their data-related problems. Specifically for this problem, I want OP to see this as a higher-level challenge in working with their structured data, and not a lower-level file problem. And for me, I only see harm in advising anyone to try and manually parse CSV (when good tools are right there to be used).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DictReader and supply it the fieldnames you ultimately want (to handle the implicit no-header case), then handle the explicit case where there was a header and now you need to skip it:

```py
import csv

header_vals = ["col1", "col2"]
header_row = {x: x for x in header_vals}

for fname in ["input1.csv", "input2.csv"]:
    with open(fname, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=header_vals)

        print(f"{fname}:")
        for row in reader:
            if row == header_row:
                print("  skipped explicit header")
                continue
            print(f"  {row}")
```

For these two files:

```
input1.csv
==========
col1,col2
r1c1,r1c2
r2c1,r2c2

input2.csv
==========
r1c1,r1c2
r2c1,r2c2
```

that prints:

```
input1.csv:
  skipped explicit header
  {'col1': 'r1c1', 'col2': 'r1c2'}
  {'col1': 'r2c1', 'col2': 'r2c2'}
input2.csv:
  {'col1': 'r1c1', 'col2': 'r1c2'}
  {'col1': 'r2c1', 'col2': 'r2c2'}
```